# Issue: Color not showing properly - why so?

Tags: android, xml

I tried to set a view groups between text views as a boundary between them but the background color of views are showing differently in each view. The image is:

[image]

The code of my activity_main.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="82"
    android:background="@color/view">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/view"
        android:layout_weight=".4"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numbers"
        style="@style/CategoryStyle"
        android:background="@color/category_numbers"
        android:text="@string/category_numbers"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".4"
        android:background="@color/view" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/family"
        style="@style/CategoryStyle"
        android:background="@color/category_family"
        android:text="@string/category_family"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/view"
        android:layout_weight=".4"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/colors"
        style="@style/CategoryStyle"
        android:background="@color/category_colors"
        android:text="@string/category_colors"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/view"
        android:layout_weight=".4"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phrases"
        style="@style/CategoryStyle"
        android:background="@color/category_phrases"
        android:text="@string/category_phrases"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/view"
        android:layout_weight=".4"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The colors code in colors.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <!-- Primary color of the app (shown in the app bar) -->
    <color name="primary_color">#000000</color>

    <!-- Primary dark color of the app (shown in the status bar) -->
    <color name="primary_dark_color">#000000</color>

    <!-- Background color for app -->
    <color name="tan_background">#FFECB3</color>

    <!-- Background color for the numbers category -->
    <color name="category_numbers">#B00020</color>

    <!-- Background color for the family members category -->
    <color name="category_family">#0336FF</color>

    <!-- Background color for the colors category -->
    <color name="category_colors">#6200EA</color>

    <!-- Background color for the phrases category -->
    <color name="category_phrases">#1B5E20</color>

    <color name="view">#FFEA00</color>
</resources>
```

It seems like the background color of textviews are affecting the background colors of view. Need help with this sort of error.

Comment: There is nothing strange in the picture. Between the TextViews you can see the color of the views.

Comment: The color for all the views is same(read the code) but the color is showing differently in all the views. Look at the picture as well closely...!!!

Comment: @Rissam Asghar -  maybe you'll be able to find out what the problem is by using LayoutInspector: run the app, navigate to the "problem screen", turn on [LayoutInspector](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector) and examine all the shown Views

Comment: @0X0nosugar is there any video support on this ??

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about that